# SQL - COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: sql

I need to create a query to do the next, with data with same CLIENT, DATE and STATUS, to select the maximum date of execution and count it. I think with an example it will be easier to undestand.

From this table for example,

```
Client        Status         Date             Date Execution        
-------       ----------     ------           ---------------------        
AB            100            22/07/2014       23/07/2014 21:35
AB            100            22/07/2014       23/07/2014 05:00
AB            100            22/07/2014       23/07/2014 19:32
AB            100            23/07/2014       24/07/2014 04:15
AB            100            23/07/2014       24/07/2014 20:19
BC            400            24/07/2014       25/07/2014 20:56
BC            400            24/07/2014       25/07/2014 03:36
BC            400            24/07/2014       25/07/2014 17:58
BC            400            24/07/2014       25/07/2014 14:51
```

I would like to obtain,

```
Client        Status         Date              Date Execution          COUNT(Distint)
-------    ----------      ------          ---------------------     ----------------------
AB             100        22/07/2014       23/07/2014 21:35             3
AB             100        23/07/2014       24/07/2014 20:19             2
BC             400        24/07/2014       25/07/2014 20:56             4
```

For the moment I did this query to do find the max date execution, but I dont know how to do for the COUNT (DISTINCT).

```
SELECT ip.CLIENT, cps.DATE, cpst.STATUS, cpst.DATE_EXE

FROM IP ip, CPS cps, CPST cpst INNER JOIN (SELECT PF_GUID, MAX(DATE_EXE)
                                          FROM CTR_PORTFOLIOS_TRG 
                                          GROUP BY PF_GUID) cpst2 ON cpst.PF_GUID=cpst2.PF_GUID

WHERE ip.PF_ID = cps.PF_ID AND cps.PF_GUID = cpst.PF_GUID
        AND cpst.STATUS IN (100,400,550)
       AND cps.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30/09/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

ORDER BY CLIENT, STATUS, DATE
```

Any help please to complete the query? Thank you very much

Comment: What database platform is this for?  Please tag accordingly.

Comment: This looks like Oracle or Postgres, because of the use of `to_date()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a basic aggregation query.  I think you might have confused yourself:

```
SELECT ip.CLIENT, cpst.STATUS, MIN(cps.date), MAX(cpst.DATE_EXE), COUNT(*)
FROM IP ip JOIN
     CPS cps
     ON ip.PF_ID = cps.PF_ID JOIN
     CPST cpst
     ON cps.PF_GUID = cpst.PF_GUID 
WHERE cpst.STATUS IN (100,400,550) AND
      cps.DATE BETWEEN DATE '2014-07-01' and DATE '2014-09-30'
GROUP BY ip.CLIENT, cps.STATUS;
```

Notes:

- Replaced the implicit joins with explicit joins.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.
- Removed the aggregation subquery.
- Changed the format to use the Oracle `DATE` identifier for a constant.
- Use `MAX()` to get the most recent date/time.
- Use `COUNT(*)` to get the count.  I'm not sure what you mean by `distinct`, but for the sample results, `count(*)` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to obtain the max date_exe from each day, not the maximum in total. That's why I did the sub select with the innner join. But it doesnt work how I did it because the count only have to have (CLIENT, STATUS, DATE) not (DATE_EXE).

Comment: SELECT ip.CLIENT, cpst.STATUS, cps.DATE, COUNT(*) FROM INT_PORTFOLIO ip, CTR_PORTFOLIOS cps, CTR_PORTFOLIOS_TRG cpst WHERE ip.PF_ID = cps.PF_ID AND cps.PF_GUID = cpst.PF_GUID AND cpst.STATUS IN (100,400,550) AND cps.DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30/09/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') GROUP BY ip.CLIENT, cpst.STATUS, cps.DATE ORDER BY CLIENT, STATUS, DATE But now i dont know how to add in the last column the max date_EXE of each day

Comment: @abetitou . . . First, use the version of the query in the answer.  I don't recognize your query at all.  If you want a day-by-day reckoning, add `date(cps.date)` or `date(cpst.DATE_EXE)` to both the `select` and `group by` (I'm not sure which you want).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Client,
        [Status],
        [Date],
        MAX([Date Execution]) [Date Execution],
        COUNT(*) [Count(Distinct)]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Client,
         [Status],
         [Date]
```